# What is the best DB/Storage/service to store logs related to my azure application?

Tags: azure, logging, storage

I am relatively new to azure. I published my new app to azure app service. I want to store and view my logs easily. What is the best place to store logs and view in Azure? Is there any built in service for that?

Thanks,
Gowtham.

Comment: Application insights would be my recommendation

Comment: Can I write console.log() and see those logs there?

Comment: Actually, you could store logs in [Diagnostics logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).